# M-itx Ryzen board that supports rdimms?

Tags: motherboard

I'm looking for a m-iitx motherboard that supports registered ecc memory on the ryzen chipset.

Does it exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TL;DR: Every AM4 ITX board (so far) supports ECC but not RDIMMs

[Registered DIMMs won't work on Ryzen, plain and simple.](https://www.anandtech.com/show/11697/the-amd-ryzen-threadripper-1950x-and-1920x-review/2) [Ryzen isn't validated for ECC support on consumer chipsets and, as a result, AMD doesn't officially support it.](http://www.hardwarecanucks.com/forum/hardware-canucks-reviews/75030-ecc-memory-amds-ryzen-deep-dive.html) ECC support is however enabled, and certain motherboard manufactures do validate ECC memory.

Here's a list of AM4 ITX boards that have been validated with ECC memory:

- [ASRock AB350 Gaming-ITX/ac](https://www.asrock.com/MB/AMD/Fatal1ty%20AB350%20Gaming-ITXac/index.asp#Memory)

  - [Adata AD4E2133W8G15-BHYA 2133 8GB UDIMM](http://www.adata.com/upload/downloadfile/Datasheet%20-%20DDR4%202133%20R-DIMM-VLP-R-DIMM-ECC-SO-DIMM_201601.pdf)
  - [Crucial CT8G4WFD824A.18FB1 2400 8GB UDIMM](http://www.memory4less.com/crucial-server-memory-ct8g4wfd824a-18fb1)
  - [Samsung M391A1G43EB1-CPBQ 2133 8GB UDIMM](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B074F489DP)
- [ASRock X370 Gaming-ITX/ac](https://www.asrock.com/mb/AMD/Fatal1ty%20X370%20Gaming-ITXac/#Memory)

  - [Adata AD4E2133W8G15-BHYA 2133 8GB UDIMM](http://www.adata.com/upload/downloadfile/Datasheet%20-%20DDR4%202133%20R-DIMM-VLP-R-DIMM-ECC-SO-DIMM_201601.pdf)
  - [Crucial CT8G4WFD824A.18FB1 2400 8GB UDIMM](http://www.memory4less.com/crucial-server-memory-ct8g4wfd824a-18fb1)
  - [Samsung M391A1G43EB1-CPBQ 2133 8GB UDIMM](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B074F489DP)
- [Asus ROG STRIX B350-I GAMING](http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/SocketAM4/ROG_STRIX_B350-I_GAMING/ROG_STRIX_B350-I_GAMING_DDR4-DRAM_Summit_CPUTestReport.pdf?_ga=2.138516086.415135241.1515101375-704863234.1450079784)

  - [Transcent TS1GLH72V1H 2133 8GB UDIMM](https://www.transcend-info.com/Embedded/Products/No-688)
- [Asus ROG STRIX X370-I GAMING](http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/SocketAM4/ROG_STRIX_X370-I_GAMING/ROG_STRIX_X370-I_GAMING_DDR4-DRAM_Summit_CPUTestReport.pdf?_ga=2.210482384.415135241.1515101375-704863234.1450079784)

  - [Transcent TS1GLH72V1H 2133 8GB UDIMM](https://www.transcend-info.com/Embedded/Products/No-688)
- [Biostar B350GTN](http://www.biostar.com.tw/app/en/mb/introduction.php?S_ID=878#memorysupport)

  - Apacer 78.B1GM4.4020B 2133 4GB UDIMM
  - Apacer 78.C1GM4.AF10B 2133 8GB UDIMM
  - Hynix HMA41GU7AFR8N-TF 2133 8GB UDIMM
- [Biostar X370GTN](http://www.biostar.com.tw/app/en/mb/introduction.php?S_ID=879#memorysupport)

  - Apacer 78.B1GM4.4020B 2133 4GB UDIMM
  - Apacer 78.C1GM4.AF10B 2133 8GB UDIMM
  - Hynix HMA41GU7AFR8N-TF 2133 8GB UDIMM
- [Gigabyte GA-AB350N-Gaming WIFI (rev. 1.0)](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-AB350N-Gaming-WIFI-rev-10#support-doc)

  - [Kingston KVR21E15S8/4 2133 4GB UDIMM](http://www.kingston.com/datasheets/KVR21E15S8_4.pdf)
  - [Kingston KVR21E15D8/8HA 2133 8GB UDIMM](https://www.kingston.com/dataSheets/KVR21E15D8_8HA.pdf)
  - [Crucial CT4G4WFS8213.9FA1 2133 4GB UDIMM](http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/memory-server-ddr4)
  - V-Color TE48G21S815 8GB UDIMM
  - V-Color TE416G21D815 16GB UDIMM

<sup>Note that so far this is every AM4 ITX motherboard out there, and I'd expect this trend to continue, so [any board here](https://pcpartpicker.com/products/motherboard/#s=33&f=8&sort=name&page=1) is likely to work.</sup>

Comment: I appreciate it man, my main concern is with rdimm memory though. Udimms are often interchangeable with regular dimms, Rdimm is often where compatibility issues arise. Unless I have big misunderstanding of it.

Comment: RDIMMs flat out won't work :/ Compatibility once you start getting into more "server grade" gear basically just becomes a bit of a bear, but most any ECC UDIMM will probably work. What do you need registered memory for in a desktop though? ECC I can understand, but typically, registered memory is only important in ultra-high memory count applications.

Comment: Honestly I don't need it for anything in particular, It's more of a fun idea to mess with since I can get server grade parts through work for practically free.

Comment: Ooooo, I like server grade parts! What about using server grade motherboard? Also, are you familiar with the homelab community?

Comment: I'm self taught so I'm a bit oblivious to the various communities out there!, I'm always looking for people to connect with though! For mitx server boards the closest I've seen to what I'd want to use would be asrocks rock rack. (what a mouthful!) It supports both the lga2011v3/4 sockets and quad channel sodimm ecc memory, as well as the xeon D boards; On the consumer side I've been looking at the x99 socket. Sadly I've yet to see a single mitx threadripper or epyc board!

Comment: Check out /r/homelab then! I've seen that board before (I think Linus had one?), but I'm fairly sure that one doesn't support RDIMMs either. My guess is that there won't be ITX boards with TR4, the socket is just too big.

Comment: I think there might still be hope, with the growing popularity of daughterboards and sff pcs. You never know. Definitely gonna check out that reddit! Thanks man!

Comment: Btw, how do I mark your post as the answer? Completely new to stack exchange.